# Does a notification go out if you add a checklist item?

Tags: trello, notifications

If all you do is go into a card and add an item to a checklist, does the assigned member get a notification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's is only a notification for completing checklist items, not adding them. All subscribed members will get a notification for completing a checklist item.

Comment: Bummer, I wish I could notify people when I add items. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this is a somewhat delayed response but I achieved this as follows;

1. code a Google App script to call the API Trello to get a snapshot of
   the Trello board/list data (store in JSON in a google sheet).
2. code a Google App script to run every X minutes to call Trello API to get same board/list data, compare with the recent snapshot, send an email notification if check lists have changed, take a new snapshot for the next script run